# How can I merge my resources stanza with that of the super POM?

Tags: maven

(I've been working with Maven for many years.  I sort of can't believe I've only now encountered this issue.)

The super POM defines its `<resources>` stanza like this:

```
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

I have a `<resources>` stanza in my `pom.xml` like this:

```
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>LICENSE</include>
    </includes>
    <targetPath>
  </resource>
</resource>
```

When I run `mvn help:effective-pom`, I can see that Maven has eliminated the super POM's (helpful) `<resources>` stanza and has replaced it with my own.

Instead, I'd like to add the contents of my `<resources>` stanza to that supplied by the super POM.

No combination of either of the `combine.children` or `combine.self` attributes placed on my `<resources>` element causes this to happen (plus I have no idea what these names are supposed to indicate, though I've read [an article on the subject](http://blog.sonatype.com/2011/01/maven-how-to-merging-plugin-configuration-in-complex-projects/)).

What obvious thing am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic attributes like `combine.children` and `combine.self` only apply on the configuration of plugins; the pom itself is transformed to a set of pojos, but the plugin-configuration is a XML-DOM. With xpp3 features we can define a merge strategy.
And yes, AFAIK resources are always overwritten, never extended. A resource doesn't have a unique identifier, so it is not possible to detect which resource-blocks should be merged, overridden or extended.